# Readable stream and callback function

Tags: node.js, stream, cassandra, ecmascript-6

I have a bit of a problem with reading the stream from cassandra (I do not even know is it possible what I am trying to achieve). So on the **cassandra-driver** git repository page there is an example how to use stream. I've tried it and it works.

But however I am trying to use so called classes from ES6 proposal with nodejs 5. I want to define model as a class and in one of the methods I am using stream (where I am fetching the data from cassandra).
Problem is with the **readable** state, where you have this.read() in callback function and now when this is called in a class this becomes a class scope so it is always undefined. I've tried extending my class with the ResultStream from **cassandra-driver** module but no luck, maybe I am not calling it properly. I've tried with the **data** state (different class and method as a callback) and it is working since data state has a argument passed as a chunk.

So the question is, how i could encapsulate this stream call in a class method, so the readable state could be read?

Example code of what I would like to achieve:

```
class Foobar {
    constructor(client) {
        this.client = client;
        this.collection = [];
        this.error;
    }
    getByProductName(query, params) {
        this.client.stream(query, params, {prepare: true})
            .on('readable', () => {
                var row;
                while(row = this.read()) { // Problem with this scope
                    this.collection.push(row);
                }
            })
            .on('error', err => {
                if(err) {
                    this.error = err;
                }
            })
            .on('end', () => {
                console.log('end');
            });
    }
}
```

Thank you for any advices.

Comment: Don't use an arrow function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could capture the `stream` instance in a closure:

```
class Foobar {
    constructor(client) {
        this.client = client;
        this.collection = [];
        this.error;
    }
    getByProductName(query, params) {
        const stream = this.client.stream(query, params, { prepare: true })
            .on('readable', () => {
                var row;
                while(row = stream.read()) { // <- use stream instance 
                    this.collection.push(row);
                }
            })
            .on('error', err => {
                if(err) {
                    this.error = err;
                }
            })
            .on('end', () => {
                console.log('end');
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, yes I ended up doing something similar like you proposed, just i used this.client.stream directly without const